# Thread concurrent file modification

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

I just started learning Scala today so this may be a very simple issue. I am trying to write to a file from multiple threads but I am only getting results from the first thread. I have done a lot of reading on `Futures` but I couldn't find an implementation that worked (most likely because I didnt understand something). Can someone explain how to have multiple threads write to the same file?

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import util.Random.nextInt
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.FileWriter;

object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val p1=1<<56
    val p2=7<<52
    val p3=0<<32

    val r = scala.util.Random   

    val fw = new FileWriter("steam_out_scala.txt", true)

for (i <- 0 to 3) {

    val thread = new Thread {
        override def run {
            val p4=r.nextInt(1000000)
            val url=("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXYYYZZZ,steamids="+((p1|p2)|(p3|p4))).toString

            try{
            val in = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url.toString,"utf-8")
            fw.write(((p1|p2)|(p3|p4)).toString)
            //fw.close()
            }
            catch{
                case e: IOException => { //catches api call fail AND file write failed
                    println("failed for num: "+(((p1|p2)|(p3|p4)).toString))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    thread.start
    //Thread.sleep(50)
}
fw.close() //moved here
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not a scala issue at all.

You create a `FileWriter` before you start the threads but you close it after the first write:

```
fw.write(((p1|p2)|(p3|p4)).toString)
fw.close()
```

So, if you'd make sure you close the `FileWriter` only after the last thread has finished. You should get further. Though, instead of using Threads you might want to have a look at Akka.